# I need an explanation for this palindrome

Tags: java, for-loop, palindrome

Can anyone explain me this palandrome from the "for loop" with an example? I do not understand how the for loop works, it would be a great deed if you guys help me understand.

```
 import java.util.*;`
 public class palindrome {

public static void main(String args[])
{
  String original, reverse = "";


  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a string to check if it is a palindrome");
  original = in.nextLine();

  int x = original.length();

  for ( int i = x - 1; i >= 0; i-- ){
     reverse  = reverse + original.charAt(i);
  }

   if (original.equals(reverse))
     System.out.println("Entered string is a palindrome.");
  else
     System.out.println("Entered string is not a palindrome.");
    }
    }
```

Comment: What is your question about this code? "Explain how this works" is not a good question.

Comment: When you don't understand such a loop, do it step by step with a pen and some paper.

Comment: This is not my code, and I've tried using a pen and a paper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

variable X is the length of the original string. Due to indexes starting at 0, that means the index of the final character is (x-1). Therefore the for loop is initialized with the variable i = x-1, in order to make the loop start on the last character of the string.

From there it adds the character at index i (at this point the last character in the string) to a new blank string. it then checks that i is greater than or equal to 0 (a check on whether the string still has more characters or if the beginning has been reached). If the condition is true (there are more characters to process) it deceases the value of i by 1, to get the second last element in the string. It then adds that to the reverse string, and checks again. and so on, and so forth until the beginning of the string is reached.

If you have input string "FooBar" it works as follows:

length = 6

i = 6-1 = 5

is 5 >= 0?  yes. 
enter loop

reverse += String(5) 
//reverse = "r"

decrease i.

i = 4

is 4 >= 0? yes
reverse += String(4)
//reverse = "ra"

decrease i

i = 3

//etc. until i is below zero

end loop

reverse = "raBooF"

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

It just reads the entered string's characters one at a time in a backwards fashion and concat's them to an empty string.

After that is the comparison.

```
randomtest
         ^  start here ( x-1 ) cuz x is full lenght, not index

randomtest
     <--^    and go backwards (i--)
```

Comment: How? I tried understanding that, please elaborate 
for ( int i = x - 1; i >= 0; i-- ){
therefore if my word is mom
will it read the 1st letter cause mom = 3 and i = x-1.... i--

Comment: The last statement in a for loop declaration (`i--`) is only executed after the body of the loop. Thus, a for loop `for(A; B; C){D;}` is equivalent to `A;  while(B){ D; C; }`

Comment: Thou speaketh the truth! Although my concerns grow over our mutual acquaintance's understanding of an abstract explanation, albeit his own.

Comment: Thanks SIzik, your comment really helped me out! You so pro :p

Answer (score 0):

```
 // let's assume 
 // String original = "question" (some random String)
 // this assigns length of the string into int variable x

 int x = original.length(); // x = 8



  // for loop starts here
  // for ex - if length of string "question" is 8 (index will be from 0 to 7)
  // so, it has to starts from last index i.e 7, which is nothing but (8-1) or (length-1) index

  // it will start from i = 7, since 7th character gives last character i.e 'n'
  // so this for loop starts picking up one character from last
  // value of 'i' (index) is decreased every time.


for ( int i = x - 1; i >= 0; i-- ){
     // in this step the character is picked (present at 'i'th index) and 
     // added to the 'reverse' string and overwritten to the 'reverse' object
     // for ex - 
     // if loop starts from i = 7, original.charAt(7) will be n in String "question", then reverse will be reverse ("" (empty string)) + 'n' which is "n"
     // next time reverse will be "n" and i will be = 6, then original.charAt(6) will be = 'o'.
     // since concatenation of reverse and original.charAt(i) has to be assigned to reverse, the new reverse will be = "no" 
     // when i = 5, reverse = "no" + 'i' = "noi"
     // i = 4,  reverse = "noi" + 't' = "noit"
     // i = 3,  reverse = "noit" + 's' = "noits"
     // i = 2,  reverse = "noits" + 'e' = "noitse"
     // i = 1,  reverse = "noitse" + 'u' = "noitseu"
     // i = 0,  reverse = "noitseu" + 'q' = "noitseuq"
     // when i = -1, loop exits, so reverse String will have "noitseuq" after for loop ends
     reverse  = reverse + original.charAt(i);
  }
```